Pipeline outputs is empty even though the pipeline is running correctly
The following code simulates a simple TFX pipeline ingesting a CSV file and converting it to TFRecord.
You can also see the corresponding notebook: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1GEytZjnNZZ7r_f9QQ9FbauohKNLGSooC?usp=sharing
output_config = example_gen_pb2.Output(split_config=
    example_gen_pb2.SplitConfig(splits=[
        example_gen_pb2.SplitConfig.Split(name='train', hash_buckets=8),
        example_gen_pb2.SplitConfig.Split(name='eval', hash_buckets=2)
    ])
)

example_gen = CsvExampleGen(
    input_base='data',
    output_config=output_config
)

pipeline_root = 'artifacts'

pipeline = Pipeline(
    pipeline_name='testing pipeline',
    pipeline_root=pipeline_root,
    components=[example_gen],
    enable_cache=True,
    metadata_connection_config=metadata.sqlite_metadata_connection_config(
        os.path.join('artifacts', 'metadata.sqlite')
    )
)

LocalDagRunner().run(pipeline)

I have manually verified that the TFRecord have been properly generated. However, the pipeline's outputs dictionaries is empty.
print(pipeline.outputs)
# output: {}
print(example_gen.outputs['examples'].get())
# output: []

This problem persists in both a .ipynb notebook and .py file.
Interestingly enough, InteractiveContext does not have this problem.
What is causing this?

In tfx, a pipeline uses Channels to shuttle information from/to ml metadata and feed it to the executor.  The pipeline, when it is running, is using those channels to substitute in the right values for example_gen.outputs['examples'].  When it is no longer running, it doesn't have those Channels active anymore.  Although the video is about custom components, it does a really good job of explaining how tfx works: https://youtu.be/_c-znj_cZvU?si=v3qIp1iC-gPthnfn
Conceptually, I think of the components producing inputs and outputs, and the pipeline facilitating the execution of these components.  For example, if there were three components that ran simultaneously at the end, which one of them should be the output?  As such, it is helpful to think of the pipeline in a few different ways: The pipeline definition (contains components which refer to inputs, outputs, execution parameters), the pipeline while it is executing (is using Channels to shuttle information back and forth from ml metadata, components are executing), and the pipeline after it has finished executing (ml metadata has information about pipeline runs).
You might've heard the term 'hermetically sealed' in the context of pipelines.  TFX does a really good job of ensuring there are no remnants of state lying around, and that you can reproduce these runs using information in ml metadata as long as you have the associated data still accessible.
Another good place to understand some of these concepts is: https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/guide
